# Personalized content

Tags: php

I would like to, clicking on a link, showing a content personalized.

```
<div class="tab_event">             
<?php
do{
    echo'                   


    <table class="preview_event">
        <td class="date_event">
            '.$row["Date"].'
        </td>
        <td class="title_event">
            <p>'.$row["Title"].'<br></p>
            <a href="">Read more !</a>
        </td>

    </table>


';
} while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

My program consist at doing a "preview" of some articles from the database.
And when you click on "read more" i would like that, automatically, you get a page where the all article is written.
But I don't have any ideas about how to do it, bcs i don't want to create a page manually for each article.
Does anyone have any idea about how to do ?
Thanks

Comment: This problem is exactly what HTML template languages are designed to solve - and PHP is at heart an HTML template language (which can also do lots of other things). So you can easily write just one script which takes a `GET` parameter - such as the article's database id - and displays the appropriate content depending on that parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to generate a `href` to another/same PHP powered page along with a query parameter with some value which uniquely identifies the article in your database.

Assuming your database table structure is similar to

```
| Id | Date       | Title                  |
|----|------------|------------------------|
| 1  | 0000-00-00 | Some catchy post title |
| 2  | 0000-00-00 | Yet another post title |
| 3  | 0000-00-00 | Some other title?      |
```

I will use `$row["Id"]` using the above table structure

```
   <div class="tab_event">             
    <?php
      do {
        echo '                   
        <table class="preview_event">
            <td class="date_event">
                '.$row["Date"].'
            </td>
            <td class="title_event">
                <p>'.$row["Title"].'<br></p>
                <a href="/showArticle.php?aid='.$row["Id"].'">Read more !</a>
            </td>

        </table>';
      } while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    ?>
```

Now access the `aid` parameter on your linked script (showArticle.php) to fetch the article from databse

```
<?php
   if (!empty($_GET['aid']) {
      // escape and verify value of `$_GET['aid']`
      // fetch and return article from database using the `$_GET['aid']` parameter
   } else {
      // tell the user no `Id` was provided
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an easy task, first of all, you need to modify your table page, and edit the read more link this :

`<a href="read.php?article=.$row['article_id'].">Read more !</a>`

Where `article_id`is whatever record's identification you wanna use to store that information when clicking the link, for example the article's id field in the database, now you create a `read.php` page, which will change its content based on the article's id in the link, so you only need to create that and not one page for each article.

Then in `read.php` you retrieve that information from the URL so that you can query the database with the correct article's ID and show its content:

```
...
...
$article_id = $_GET['article'];

// then you query the database using that variable (using whatever method you prefer, this in just an example)

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT title, date, content FROM articles WHERE articles.id = " . $article_id);

$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This way you can retrieve the single's article information and show them on the `read.php` page , creating only one page which changes its content based on which link you click.

Also, worth mention that you should remove that `do...while`, `for` and `foreach` loops are way more elegant.

One example would be (assuming that the variable containing the results is called `$rows`) :

```
<table> <!-- table tag outside of the loop, otherwise for each article a table is created, which is wrong -->
 <tbody>
  <?php

  foreach($rows as $article) {
   echo "<tr>"; // since we need one row for each article, we include the tr tag in the loop
   echo "<td>".$article['title']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$article['date']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$article['author']."</td>";
   ...
   ...
   echo "</tr>"; // and we close the row
  }

  ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```